# Appending the mode of a dataframe column only creates value in first row of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

After encountering some broken csv files in the past I am working on a smale python code which allows to filter out this faulty lines so I can manually check them for a pattern and if possible fix them.

However when wanting to append the right amount of columns I expect the file to have I only get the "mode" most frequent observation of delimiter in the first row and not all rows.

This kind of broken csvs file usually comes if a row has more separating delimiters than it actually has columns (e.g. if the name of the client has also a ; and then excel splits that as well and so moves all columns one to the right) I want per chunk I load into see the number of delimiters in the first column compare it to the "right" number of delimiters for the chunk (I simplify this by using mode as consensus) and then simply send this faulty rows to a list.

I believe the error comes from how I use pandas I am new to coding and while pandas seems perfect to handle the data i am still reading a lot about how to properly address column and rows.

The code goes through my hundreds of csv files loads them in in chunks based on a absolutely uncommon delimiter in this case |. This creates a data dataframe where I have the whole csv row combined in one field what allows me than in turn to count the correct delimiter (in this case ;).

```
la=[]
for filename in all_files:
     for chunk in pd.read_csv(filename, sep='|', chunksize=1000000):
         chunk['filename'] = os.path.basename(filename)
         chunk["delimeters"] = chunk.iloc[:,0].str.count(',')
         chunk['good delimeter'] = chunk["delimeters"].mode()

         for index, row in chunk.iterrows():
             if row['delimeters'] != chunk['good delimeter']:
               la.append(row)
             else: 
               print("all good")


print(la)
```

My main problem is currently that when I look into my chunk dataframe the count of delimiter works well however the mode is only appended to the first row so when i look at chunk it looks as follows:

```
    Name| Filename| delimetier| good delimeter
    A     123       48         48
    B     123       48         Nan
    C     123       49         Nan
    D     123       48         Nan
```

However I would like to have the mode of the delimiter column appended to all so that I can compare them with the if statement and so filter out the fault rows.

When now running this script for this post I also encounter the following error:

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

However I assume this is a follow up error caused by the Nan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is not returning/assigning a scalar value, but rather a `numpy` array:

```
chunk['good delimeter'] = chunk["delimeters"].mode()
```

Change it to:

```
chunk['good delimeter'] = chunk["delimeters"].mode()[0]
```

Which will assign the mode value to all rows with a type of numpy.float64.